# Already S-Off, need root on HTC One M8 Verizon

Tags: root-access, verizon, htc-one-m8

I'm relatively new to Android and I'm just trying to get root on my HTC One M8 Verizon device. I've successfully used the SunShine utility to S-Off, but I'm just really confused about what to do next to get permanent root. I don't care about custom ROMs and I'd really prefer not to have to install TWRP if I don't have to. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

FWIW, I've got the Android SDK and associated tools (adb, etc.) installed, and I am successfully able to connect to my device. Just don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. There's a support channel, #sunshine-support on irc.freenode.org. Just go in there and type `!info ring`, and one of the devs pretty much instantly responds. Or, you can just type `!info getroot` directly and let them get some shut-eye. Anyways, that will provide you with a link to an apk called SUInstaller. At the time of writing it's at: http://theroot.ninja/apks/SUInstaller.apk. But, if it moves, follow the instructions I just gave to get the current one.

Anyways, you install this app and it will reboot your phone (installing su in the process). Then, just download SuperSU from the Play Store and follow the prompts. Reboot when it tells you to and then give it about five minutes after the phone boots up for everything to finish loading. Then, you can use something like [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) (also available on the Play Store) to verify that you have root access.